# Mini HttpClient json post by Action parameter

Tags: c#, json, async-await, rest

This is an implementation of HttpClient Json Post by Action parameter.

**Logic:**

> - It is mainly convenient to pass the url and object (automatically converted to json by Json.Net), and can use Action as a parameter to customize function.
> - default timeout is 15 sec , if you want to change the time , it could change timeout parameter value.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Test()
    {
        //SuccessExecute
        await Execute("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", new { value = "ITWeiHan" }); //Result : {"value": "ITWeiHan","id": 101}
        //ErrorExecute
        await Execute("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/error404", new { value = "ITWeiHan" }); //Result : Error 404
    }

    public static async Task Execute(string url, object reqeustBody)
    {
        await HttpClientHelper.PostByJsonContentTypeAsync(url, reqeustBody
            , successFunction: responsebody =>
            {
                //Your Success Logic
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
                Console.WriteLine(responsebody);
            }, errorFunction: httpRequestException =>
            {
                //Your Error Solution Logic
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.WriteLine(httpRequestException.Message);
            }
        );
    }
}

public static class HttpClientHelper
{
    public static async Task PostByJsonContentTypeAsync(string url, object reqeustBody, Action<string> successFunction, Action<HttpRequestException> errorFunction, int timeout = 15)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqeustBody);

        using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) })
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            request.Content = stringContent;
            try
            {
                using (var httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    successFunction(responseBody);
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                errorFunction(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great job. Here are some minor notes though.

In newer versions of C# you can leverage `async Main` in order not to wait for your test method.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Test();
}
```

You can speed things up a bit with executing your tests in parallel

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var successExecute = Execute("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", new { value = "ITWeiHan" }); //Result : {"value": "ITWeiHan","id": 101}
    var errorExecute = Execute("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/error404", new { value = "ITWeiHan" }); //Result : Error 404
    await Task.WhenAll(successExecute, errorExecute);
}
```

Also, `PostByJsonContentTypeAsync` throws couple of more exceptions. Namely `InvalidOperationException` and `ArgumentNullExceptions`. Are you intentionally not handling them?

Comment: thanks , yes , i only Focus on HttpRequestException ,user can edit exception class lilke Exception.